# Email not sent from custom module

Tags: email-templates, magento2.4.6

I'm trying to send an email from the custom module, for that I have created a controller file, XML file and html file,
below is my code

app/code/Magelearn/Customform/Controller/Index/
Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Magelearn\Customform\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magelearn\Customform\Model\CustomformFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME = 'trans_email/ident_support/name';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL = 'trans_email/ident_support/email';

    /**
     * @var Customform
     */
    protected $_customform;
    protected $uploaderFactory;
    protected $adapterFactory;
    protected $filesystem;

    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_inlineTranslation;
    protected $_logLoggerInterface;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomformFactory $customform,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,

        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        LoggerInterface $logLoggerInterface,    
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_customform = $customform;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;

        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $logLoggerInterface;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    try {
        //$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $data = $this->validatedParams();
        if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
            try{
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
                $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('magelearn/customform');
                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );
                }
                
                $imagePath = 'magelearn/customform'.$result['file'];
                $data['image'] = $imagePath;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
        }
        $customform = $this->_customform->create();
        $customform->setData($data);
        if($customform->save()){
            
            // Send email
            $this->sendEmail($data);

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Your inquiry has been submitted successfully.'));
        }else{
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.'));
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.'));
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->error($e->getMessage());
    }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customform');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
/**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function validatedParams()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (trim($request->getParam('first_name')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the First Name and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('last_name')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the Last Name and try again.'));
        }
        if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('phone')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the Phone Number and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('message')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter your message and try again.'));
        }
        return $request->getParams();
    }    

    /**
     * Send email
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendEmail($data)
    {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        
        $emailTemplate = 'customform_email_template'; 

        // Retrieve store Name
        $storeName = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_general/email',
            $storeScope
        );

        // Retrieve store email ID
        $storeEmail = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_general/name',
            $storeScope
        );
        
        $emailSender = [
            'name' => $storeName, 
            'email' => $storeEmail, 
        ];
        
        $emailRecipient = [
            'name' => $data['first_name'], 
            'email' => $data['email'], 
        ];
        
        $emailVars = [
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'phone'      => $data['phone'],
            'message'    => $data['message'],
        ];
        
        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
        
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplate,$storeScope)
            ->setTemplateOptions([
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $storeId,
            ])
            ->setTemplateVars($emailVars)
            ->setFrom($emailSender)
            ->addTo($emailRecipient['email'], $emailRecipient['name'])
            ->getTransport();
            
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug('Email sent successfully.');

        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
    }    
}
```

app/code/Magelearn/Customform/etc/
customform_email_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="customform_email_template" label="Custom Module Email Template" file="customform_email_template.html" type="html" module="Magelearn_Customform" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Magelearn/Customform/view/frontend/email
customform_email_template.html

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<h1>New Form Submission</h1>
<p>First Name: {{var first_name}}</p>
<p>Last Name: {{var last_name}}</p>
<p>Name: {{var name}}</p>
<p>Email: {{var email}}</p>
<p>Phone: {{var phone}}</p>
<p>Message: {{var message}}</p>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

error is :

> [2023-06-21T11:28:14.220698+00:00] main.ERROR: Email template
> 'customform_email_template' is not defined. [] []

Comment: one time you need to check the mail send from root directory or not create on file on project root and add this php code "mail("gelo@ldfh.com","My subject","message);"

Comment: I think you need to change the file name app/code/Magelearn/Customform/etc/ customform_email_template.xml to app/code/Magelearn/Customform/etc/email_templates.xml

Comment: @Priya ok so i need to change file name customform_email_template.xml to email_templates.xml and in controller $emailTemplate = 'customform_email_template'; need to remaning same?

Comment: okay @Rushikesh Solanki

Answer (score 2):

Rename : **From** `customform_email_template.xml` **To** `email_templates.xml` File name.

Path : `app/code/Magelearn/Customform/etc/email_templates.xml`

Comment: Approve the answer if it's correct...+1